# Improving class for parallelising parts of main codebase

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This is a class I wrote for parallelising certain parts of my main codebase. How could this code be improved in terms of making it shorter, more secure, and more efficient?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace System.SMP
{
    public static class Parallel
    {
        #region Context Structs
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private struct WhileContext
        {
            public Func<Object> ConditionDelegate;
            public Action WorkerDelegate;
            public Action WorkerCompleteDelegate;
            public Int32 WorkerID;
            public Boolean WorkerThreadSafeExec;
            public Boolean CompleteThreadSafeExec;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private struct ForContext
        {
            public Int32 LoopFrom;
            public Int32 LoopTo;
            public Action<Object> WorkerDelegate;
            public Action WorkerCompleteDelegate;
            public Int32 WorkerID;
            public Boolean WorkerThreadSafeExec;
            public Boolean CompleteThreadSafeExec;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private struct ForEachContext
        {
            public Type DataCollectionType;
            public IEnumerable<object> DataCollection;
            public Action<object> WorkerDelegate;
            public Action WorkerCompleteDelegate;
            public Int32 WorkerID;
            public Boolean WorkerThreadSafeExec;
            public Boolean CompleteThreadSafeExec;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Spawn Methods

        public static void SpawnInToWait(Action<object> worker, object param, ref Wait waitObject, String workerName)
        {
            if (waitObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("waitObject cannot be null");
            if (worker == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("worker cannot be null");

            Thread thread = new Thread((ParameterizedThreadStart)(worker as Delegate));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Name = workerName;

            waitObject.AddThreadToWaitFor(thread);

            thread.Start(param);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public While Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <returns>Wait object</returns>
        public static Wait While(Func<Object> condition, Action worker)
        {
            return While(condition, worker, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <param name="workerComplete">Delegate that is called after each worker has completed</param>
        /// <returns>Wait object</returns>
        public static Wait While(Func<Object> condition, Action worker, Action workerComplete)
        {
            return While(condition, worker, workerComplete, Environment.ProcessorCount);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <param name="workerComplete">Delegate that is called after each worker has completed</param>
        /// <param name="workerCount">Number of workers to spawn</param>
        /// <returns>Wait object</returns>
        public static Wait While(Func<Object> condition, Action worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount)
        {
            return While(condition, worker, workerComplete, workerCount, false); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <param name="workerComplete">Delegate that is called after each worker has completed</param>
        /// <param name="workerCount">Number of workers to spawn</param>
        /// <param name="threadSafeWorker"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Wait While(Func<Object> condition, Action worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount, Boolean threadSafeWorker)
        {
            return While(condition, worker, workerComplete, workerCount, threadSafeWorker, true); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <param name="workerComplete">Delegate that is called after each worker has completed</param>
        /// <param name="workerCount">Number of workers to spawn</param>
        /// <param name="threadSafeWorker"></param>
        /// <param name="threadSafeComplete"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Wait While(Func<Object> condition, Action worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount, Boolean threadSafeWorker, Boolean threadSafeComplete)
        {
            if (condition == null) return null;
            if (worker == null) return null;

            Wait waitObject = new Wait();

            Int32 numWorkers = workerCount > 0 ? workerCount : Environment.ProcessorCount;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
            {
                SpawnInToWait(
                    _While, 
                    new WhileContext()
                    { 
                        ConditionDelegate = condition, 
                        WorkerDelegate = worker, 
                        WorkerCompleteDelegate = workerComplete,
                        WorkerID = i,
                        WorkerThreadSafeExec = threadSafeWorker,
                        CompleteThreadSafeExec = threadSafeComplete
                    },
                    ref waitObject,
                    "While_Worker_" + i
                );
            }

            return waitObject;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private While Methods
        private static void _While(Object obj)
        {
            WhileContext whileCtx = (WhileContext)obj;

            ThreadSafeCall threadSafeCondition = new ThreadSafeCall();

            while (((bool)threadSafeCondition.Call(whileCtx.ConditionDelegate)))
            {
                if (whileCtx.WorkerThreadSafeExec) (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(whileCtx.WorkerDelegate);
                else whileCtx.WorkerDelegate();
            }

            if (whileCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate != null)
            {
                if (whileCtx.CompleteThreadSafeExec) (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(whileCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate);
                else whileCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Do Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a do while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <returns>Wait object</returns>
        public static Wait Do(Func<Object> condition, Action worker)
        {
            return Do(condition, worker, null, Environment.ProcessorCount);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a do while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <param name="workerComplete">Delegate that is called after each worker has completed</param>
        /// <returns>Wait object</returns>
        public static Wait Do(Func<Object> condition, Action worker, Action workerComplete)
        {
            return Do(condition, worker, workerComplete, Environment.ProcessorCount);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a do while loop usng <paramref name="condition"/> as a test condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">Delegate that must return true to continue the loop or false to exit</param>
        /// <param name="worker">Delegate that contains the body of the loop</param>
        /// <param name="workerComplete">Delegate that is called after each worker has completed</param>
        /// <param name="workerCount">Number of workers to spawn</param>
        /// <returns>Wait object</returns>
        public static Wait Do(Func<Object> condition, Action worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount)
        {
            if (condition == null) return null;
            if (worker == null) return null;

            Wait waitObject = new Wait();

            Int32 numWorkers = workerCount > 0 ? workerCount : Environment.ProcessorCount;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
            {
                SpawnInToWait(
                    _Do,
                    new WhileContext()
                    {
                        ConditionDelegate = condition,
                        WorkerDelegate = worker,
                        WorkerCompleteDelegate = workerComplete,
                        WorkerID = i
                    }, 
                    ref waitObject, 
                    "Do_Worker_" + i
                );
            }

            return waitObject;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Do Methods
        private static void _Do(Object obj)
        {
            WhileContext whileCtx = (WhileContext)obj;

            ThreadSafeCall threadSafeCondition = new ThreadSafeCall();

            do
            {
                (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(whileCtx.WorkerDelegate);
            } while ((bool)threadSafeCondition.Call(whileCtx.ConditionDelegate));

            if (whileCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate != null)
            {
                (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(whileCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public For Methods
        public static Wait For(Int32 from, Int32 to, Action<Object> worker)
        {
            return For(from, to, worker, null);
        }

        public static Wait For(Int32 from, Int32 to, Action<Object> worker, Action workerComplete)
        {
            return For(from, to, worker, workerComplete, Environment.ProcessorCount);
        }

        public static Wait For(Int32 from, Int32 to, Action<Object> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount)
        {
            return For(from, to, worker, workerComplete, workerCount, false);
        }

        public static Wait For(Int32 from, Int32 to, Action<Object> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount, Boolean threadSafe)
        {
            return For(from, to, worker, workerComplete, workerCount, threadSafe, true);
        }

        public static Wait For(Int32 from, Int32 to, Action<Object> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount, Boolean threadSafe, Boolean threadSafeComplete)
        {
            if (worker == null) return null;
            if (to < from) return null;
            if (to == from) return null;

            Wait waitObject = new Wait();

            Int32 numWorkers = workerCount > 0 ? workerCount : Environment.ProcessorCount;
            Int32 itterations = to - from;
            numWorkers = numWorkers > itterations ? itterations : numWorkers;
            Int32 step = (Int32)Math.Ceiling((Decimal)itterations / (Decimal)numWorkers);

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
            {
                SpawnInToWait(
                    _For,
                    new ForContext() 
                    { 
                        WorkerDelegate = worker, 
                        WorkerCompleteDelegate = workerComplete, 
                        LoopFrom = i * step, 
                        LoopTo = Math.Min((i + 1) * step, to), 
                        WorkerID = i,
                        WorkerThreadSafeExec = threadSafe,
                        CompleteThreadSafeExec = threadSafeComplete
                    },
                    ref waitObject, 
                    "For_Worker_" + i
                );
            }

            return waitObject;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private For Methods
        private static void _For(Object obj)
        {
            ForContext forCtx = (ForContext)obj;

            for (Int32 i = forCtx.LoopFrom; i < forCtx.LoopTo; i++)
            {
                if (forCtx.WorkerThreadSafeExec) (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(forCtx.WorkerDelegate, (object)i);
                else forCtx.WorkerDelegate((object)i);
            }

            if (forCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate != null)
            {
                if (forCtx.CompleteThreadSafeExec) (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(forCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate);
                else forCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public ForEach Methods
        public static Wait ForEach<T>(ICollection<T> collection, Action<T> worker)
            where T : class
        {
            return ForEach<T>(collection, worker, null);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach<T>(ICollection<T> collection, Action<T> worker, Action workerComplete)
            where T : class
        {
            return ForEach<T>(collection, worker, workerComplete, Environment.ProcessorCount);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach<T>(ICollection<T> collection, Action<T> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount)
            where T : class
        {
            return ForEach((ICollection<object>)collection, (Action<Object>)worker, workerComplete, workerCount);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach(ICollection<object> collection, Action<object> worker)
        {
            return ForEach(collection, worker, null);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach(ICollection<object> collection, Action<object> worker, Action workerComplete)
        {
            return ForEach(collection, worker, workerComplete, Environment.ProcessorCount);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach(IEnumerable<object> collection, Action<object> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount)
        {
            return ForEach(collection, worker, workerComplete, workerCount, false);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach(IEnumerable<object> collection, Action<object> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount, Boolean threadSafe)
        {
            return ForEach(collection, worker, workerComplete, workerCount, false, true);
        }

        public static Wait ForEach(IEnumerable<object> collection, Action<object> worker, Action workerComplete, Int32 workerCount, Boolean threadSafe, Boolean threadSafeComplete)
        {
            Int32 total = collection.Count();
            Int32 numWorkers = workerCount > 0 ? workerCount : Environment.ProcessorCount;
            Int32 skip = total / numWorkers;

            Wait waitObject = new Wait();

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
            {
                SpawnInToWait(
                    _ForEach,
                    new ForEachContext()
                    {
                        DataCollection = collection.GetRange(i * skip, Math.Min(skip, total - (i * skip))),
                        WorkerDelegate = worker,
                        WorkerCompleteDelegate = workerComplete,
                        WorkerID = i,
                        DataCollectionType = collection.GetEnumerator().Current.GetType(),
                        WorkerThreadSafeExec = threadSafe
                    },
                    ref waitObject,
                    "ForEach_Worker_" + i
                );
            }

            return waitObject;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private ForEach Methods
        private static void _ForEach(object obj)
        {
            ForEachContext forEachCtx = (ForEachContext)obj;

            foreach (object dataObject in forEachCtx.DataCollection)
            {
                if (forEachCtx.WorkerDelegate != null)
                {
                    if (forEachCtx.WorkerThreadSafeExec) (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(forEachCtx.WorkerDelegate, (object)dataObject);
                    else forEachCtx.WorkerDelegate((object)dataObject);
                }
            }

            if (forEachCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate != null)
            {
                if (forEachCtx.CompleteThreadSafeExec) (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(forEachCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate);
                else forEachCtx.WorkerCompleteDelegate();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Extension Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Extension method that allows you to fetch a range from <paramref name="start"/> to <paramref name="end"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">IEnumerable type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">Any IEnumerable (list, dictionary..)</param>
        /// <param name="start">start index</param>
        /// <param name="end">end index</param>
        /// <returns>New IEnumerable of size end-start with the required items</returns>
        private static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int start, int end)
        {
            using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                var i = 0;
                while (i < start && e.MoveNext()) { i++; }
                while (i < end && e.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return e.Current;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">IEnumerable type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <returns>Number of items in <paramref name="source"/></returns>
        private static Int32 Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            Int32 result = 0;
            try
            {
                ICollection<T> c = source as ICollection<T>;
                if (c != null) throw new Exception("source is not a collection");

                result = c.Count;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) result++;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Wait Class
        /// <summary>
        /// Class to allow the syncronisation of operations within Parallel
        /// </summary>
        public class Wait
        {
            #region Public Events
            public event Action OnComplete;
            #endregion

            private Thread asyncThread = null;
            private List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="t"></param>
            internal void AddThreadToWaitFor(Thread t)
            {
                threadList.Add(t);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            public void WaitForThreads()
            {
                foreach (Thread threadHandle in threadList)
                {
                    if (threadHandle.IsAlive) threadHandle.Join();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            public void WaitForThreadsAsync()
            {
                WaitForThreadsAsync(null);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="complete"></param>
            public void WaitForThreadsAsync(Action complete)
            {
                asyncThread = new Thread(_ThreadChecker);

                asyncThread.Start(complete);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="o"></param>
            private void _ThreadChecker(object o)
            {
                Action onCompleteDelegate = (Action)o;

                WaitForThreads();

                if (OnComplete != null)
                {
                    Delegate[] onCompleteList = OnComplete.GetInvocationList();
                    foreach (Action onCompleteHandle in onCompleteList)
                    {
                        (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(onCompleteHandle);
                    }
                }

                if (onCompleteDelegate != null)
                {
                    Delegate[] onCompleteList = onCompleteDelegate.GetInvocationList();
                    foreach (Action onCompleteHandle in onCompleteList)
                    {
                        (new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(onCompleteHandle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wrapper class for making thread safe calls to any ISynchronizeInvoke based class, including Form's
        /// </summary>
        private class ThreadSafeCall
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Checks if <paramref name="action"/>'s target is ISynchronizeInvoke based, if so, invokes action, otherwise, simply calls action
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="action">Zero param, null return delegate</param>
            public void Call(Action action)
            {
                try
                {
                    ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                    if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
                    {
                        invokable.Invoke(action, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        action();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //not really sure what to do with these in this particular instance
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Checks if <paramref name="action"/>'s target is ISynchronizeInvoke based, if so, invokes action, otherwise, simply calls action
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="action">Single param, null return delegate</param>
            /// <param name="param">param to pass to <paramref name="action"/></param>
            public void Call(Action<object> action, object param)
            {
                try
                {
                    ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                    if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
                    {
                        invokable.Invoke(action, new object[] { param });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        action(param);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //not really sure what to do with these in this particular instance
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Checks if <paramref name="action"/>'s target is ISynchronizeInvoke based, if so, invokes action, otherwise, simply calls action
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="action">Zero param, object return delegate</param>
            /// <returns>return value of <paramref name="action"/></returns>
            public object Call(Func<object> action)
            {
                try
                {
                    ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                    if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
                    {
                        return invokable.Invoke(action, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return action();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //not really sure what to do with these in this particular instance
                }

                return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Checks if <paramref name="action"/>'s target is ISynchronizeInvoke based, if so, invokes action, otherwise, simply calls action
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="action">Single param, object return delegate</param>
            /// <param name="param">param to pass to <paramref name="action"/></param>
            /// <returns>return value of <paramref name="action"/></returns>
            public object Call(Func<object, object> action, object param)
            {
                try
                {
                    ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                    if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
                    {
                        return invokable.Invoke(action, new object[] { param });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return action(param);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //not really sure what to do with these in this particular instance
                }

                return null;
            }

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this do that the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) doesn't?

Comment: my library creates the threads you ask for right away rather than being restricted to the threadpool

Comment: @bizzehdee If you want a separate `Thread` for each `Task`, use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. But quite often, what `ThreadPool` does is going to be more efficient than that.

Comment: @bizzehdee - It *can't* spawn more threads than the threadpool.  As I understand it, the threadpool can be as large as your memory can handle, and runs as many tasks as your CPU will handle.  So you're not going to break those limits with your own code.

Comment: That being said, if you can post comparison numbers between using your code and using TPL or `Thread`s and yours is significantly better, I'll be really impressed.

Comment: What's your reasoning for using `Int32` over `int`? Particularly for the loop index?